# Is "Ghettopoly" legal?

Tags: copyright

I wouldn't say illegal as in criminal. However, I've heard someone sue "Ghettopoly" and win.

I check [Is it legal to publish a game that already exists but it was 100% developed by me](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57946/is-it-legal-to-publish-a-game-that-already-exists-but-it-was-100-developed-by-m)

It says rules of the games cannot be copyrighted. What about likeness, etc.?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghettopoly

Says he has to pay damage. Why? It's obvious that ghettopoly is not the same with monopoly. Also I've heard parody is protected.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Wikipedia article, the ruling against "Ghettopoly" was a [default judgment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_judgment): the defendant failed to produce documents that the court had ordered him to.  Since a default judgment is based around procedural issues, it establishes no precedents for the issue the case is based on: you can't say if "Ghettopoly" violates Hasbro's trademarks on Monopoly or not.